# Java for loop with empty initialization

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Why does the below output `5` instead of `25`?

```
public class test{

    public test()
    {
        int i =0;
        int j =0;
        int u = 0;

        for (; i<=4; i++)
        {
            for (; j<=4; j++)
            {
                u++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(u);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();        
    }
}
```

Comment: What diagnostic approaches did you try? Did you step through the code? Add logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because j is never reset back to 0.

the 1st inner loop iteration runs j from 0 to 4 (incrementing u 5 times in total making it 5) and then never runs again as j remains at 4 - so the rest of the outer loop iterations (i=1 to i=4) do nothing.

Comment: OMG!! Thanks. Didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Because first time after j became 4 that for loop never execute again...

If you want to get 25, set j=0 inside before starting inner loop or initialize j to 0 in inner loop initialization..